# using array elements in minimization

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have switched from mupad to *Mathematica*, however the syntax is completely different here. I want to

```
Minimize [{Sum[(y[[i]]-3)^2,{i,1,c}], Sum[y[[i]],{i,1,c}]==10},y[[i]]]
```

for parameter `c`. *Mathematica* shows me

> Part::pspec: Part specification i is neither a machine-sized integer nor a list of machine-sized integers.

Would you please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you can define a vector of all the y's

z = Array[y, 3]

where I'll use 3 for concreteness. Now you can minimize your function the over the vector `z` using

```
 Minimize[{(z - 3).(z - 3), Total[z] == 10}, z]
```

which returns the answer:

```
{1/3, {y[1] -> 10/3, y[2] -> 10/3, y[3] -> 10/3}}
```

So the minimum value is 1/3 and this is achieved at the point where `y[1]=y[2]=y[3]=10/3`. Somewhat more generally, you can replace the "3" in the minimize command with any vector:

```
v= {2.06, 5.83`, 7.86`};
Minimize[{(z - v).(z - v), Total[z] == 10}, z]
```

which returns the answer:

```
{11.0208, {y[1] -> 0.143333, y[2] -> 3.91333, y[3] -> 5.94333}}
```

Or perhaps different constraint functions such as known mean and variance:

```
Minimize[{(z - v).(z - v), Mean[z] == 5.3636, Variance[z] == 5.2545}, z]
```

which also gives a nice simple answer.

Comment: If `c` i.e., number of elements in z can be defined as a parameter?

Comment: I thought you wanted a numerical solution? That means `c` needs to take on some concrete value. The above method works for any `c`, but it needs to be something.

Comment: Thank you for your help. My code is  (in mathematica): `yppA = Array[ypp, 3] 
Minimize[{c2 \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(3\)]
\*SuperscriptBox[\((yppA[[i]] - {2.06`, 5.83`, 7.86`}[[
         i]])\), \(2\)]\) + c1 \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(3\)]
\*SuperscriptBox[\((yppA[[i]] - {2.2`, 5.45`, 7.47`}[[
         i]])\), \(2\)]\), 
  Mean[yppA] == 5.3636 && Variance[yppA] == 5.2545}, yppA]`. But it shows some errors: NMinimize::nnum: "The function value 216.338\ c1+228.797\ c2 is not a number at {ypp[1],ypp[2],ypp[3]} = {14.4555,0.918621,0.716689}"

Comment: Sorry for bad formatting

Comment: @remo you can update your question to show additional code.

Comment: Thank you for your help. As I understood, I could not use `c` as a parameter for optimization. By the way, it helped me alot. Thanks again.

Comment: I would not be surprised if it were possible to keep `c` a free variable... but not the way this answer is set up -- and certainly not if you expect a numerical answer! If your problem really requires c be unspecified, why not ask another question where that is clear -- maybe someone else will see how to do it. One way to go about it would be to leave everything as a function of `c`, take the derivative, set that to zero, and solve for `c`. This might be feasible.