# How to solve this simple equation?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I want to minimize a quadratic equation, but Mathematica does not solve it and only rewrites the solution. I wonder if there exist any way I can skip the computation by hand (I can solve it using Lagrangian method, but it is too long).

```
y = {y1, y2, y3}
yp = {yp1, yp2, yp3}
ypp = {ypp1, ypp2, ypp3}
Minimize[{(ypp1 - yp1)^2 + (ypp2 - yp2)^2 + (ypp3 - yp3)^2,  
           Mean[ypp] == 0 && Variance[ypp] == 1}, ypp]
```

Comment: I'd shift `ypp` and work out the new mean and variance, then use `Minimize[{Total[(ypp)^2], Mean[ypp] == a, 
  Simplify[Variance[ypp], Assumptions -> {ypp \[Element] Reals}] == 
   b}, ypp, Reals]`.

Comment: This is a repeat of this question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25845/using-array-elements-in-minimization/25849#25849 (last version in the answer)

Comment: @bills You can vote to mark it as a duplicate. To do that (in case you don't know), click the "close" link > duplicate > enter the URL of the question.

Comment: But the program above produces:    Minimize::infeas: There are no values of {ypp1,ypp2,ypp3} for which the constraints 1/3 (ypp1+ypp2+ypp3)==0&&1/3 (ypp1^2+ypp2^2-ypp2 ypp3+ypp3^2-ypp1 (ypp2+ypp3))=={5,3,6,3} are satisfied and the objective function ypp1^2+ypp2^2+ypp3^2 is real valued.

Comment: @bill I believe there is a difference. yp1, yp2, and yp3 are symbolical here, contrary to v in your previous answer, and you don't get a result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, variance uses `Conjugate` and that stumbles `Minimize` if ypp is symbolic. It can    be mended with `ComplexExpand`.  Secondly, evaluation is going for long. I supect it is due to many variants of relative positions of yp components. Setting the order explicitely, say `yp1<yp2<yp3`, gives the result:

```
y = {y1, y2, y3}
yp = {yp1, yp2, yp3}
ypp = {ypp1, ypp2, ypp3}
Minimize[{(ypp1 - yp1)^2 + (ypp2 - yp2)^2 + (ypp3 - yp3)^2, 
  Mean[ypp] == 0 && Variance[ypp] == 1 // ComplexExpand,  yp1 < yp2 < yp3}, ypp][[1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

$$
-\frac{4 \sqrt{\text{yp1}^2-\text{yp1} \text{yp2}-\text{yp1} \text{yp3}+\text{yp2}^2-\text{yp2}
   \text{yp3}+\text{yp3}^2}}{\sqrt{3}}+\text{yp1}^2+\text{yp2}^2+\text{yp3}^2+2
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's really wonderful why such a simple question takes too long.

Comment: Nice trick. (+1)